# alert mysql column`s comment using php

Tags: php, mysql, alert

I want to change my field comment using php but there is a problem!!

I need to get other column`s features :|

this is my code(gets all column features):

```
$query = "
        SELECT 
            *
            FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName' AND 
                    TABLE_NAME = '$tableName' AND 
                    COLUMN_NAME = '".$row->name."'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query.'<br>'.mysql_error());
    $tempRow = mysql_fetch_object($result);
```

this is my code that changes the comment

```
 $query = "ALTER TABLE `$tableName` 
            MODIFY  `".$row->name."` 
            ".$tempRow->COLUMN_TYPE." 
            DEFAULT ".$tempRow->COLUMN_DEFAULT."
            COMMENT '$comment'"   ;


        $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query.'<br>'.mysql_error());
```

but problem is that i lose some features , for example , outo increament , primary key ...

is there any way that i dont need to write all features , just change comment like update query ?!! if not how I should correct this query?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if ($tempRow->IS_NULLABLE == "NO")
        {
            $nullStr =" Not null ";
        }else
        {
            $nullStr ="  null ";
        }            

        if (strlen($tempRow->COLUMN_DEFAULT) >0 )
        {
            $defaultStr = "DEFAULT ".$tempRow->COLUMN_DEFAULT;
        }else
        {
            $defaultStr ="  ";
        }

        if (strlen($tempRow->COLLATION_NAME )>0)
        {
            $collateStr = "collate " . $tempRow->COLLATION_NAME ;
        }
         $comment .= implode("|",$info);
        $query = "ALTER TABLE `$tableName` 
            MODIFY  `".$row->name."` 
            ".$tempRow->COLUMN_TYPE." 
            ".$nullStr."
            ".$extraStr."
            ".$defaultStr."
            ". $tempRow->EXTRA."
            ". $collateStr."

            COMMENT '$comment'"   ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that, but there is no way to just change a single feature. You always have to specify all features that the column has. So extend your query to reflect all the column's features. All you need for that should be in `$tempRow`.